# electron-reload does not detect file changes in subdirectory

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

So I am newbie to JS world and electron. I have following structure

```
root
|-html
    |-- index.html
    |-- others
         |-- other.html
|-js
   |--main
       |-- main.js
   |--render
       |-- render.js
|-css
|-images
|-node_modules
|-others
```

I have a hello world electron App.
Now I want to reload app/window when code changes. For this I am using [electron-reload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-reload)
When I have main.js, render.js, index.html basically everything in root electron-reload works fine.
But when I move the files to above structure it fails to reload.
Here is my electron-reload configuration

```
require('electron-reload')([
                          __dirname, 
                          '${__dirname}/../../html/**/*.html',
                          '${__dirname}/../../js/**/*.js',
                          '${__dirname}/../../css/**/*.css'
                        ], {
                          electron: require('${__dirname}/../../node_modules/electron')
      });
```

Please note I aint expert with glob patterns so idea is to say --

- All JS in the directory and subdirectory --> **/*.js
- All HTML in the
  directory and subdirectory --> **/*.html
- All CSS in the directory and
  subdirectory --> **/*.css

Would appreciate if someone can point me to right direction

I am on Windows 10
and here is my package.json content

```
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.8.2",
    "electron-reload": "^1.2.2"
  }
```

Comment: You want an auto reload? Or just reload to see chances in your code? I don't understand. You can just press Command + R (Mac) and I think CTRL + R on Windows

Comment: auto reload. I dont want to do refresh manually, let my command line do the reload without manual intervention.

Answer (score 0):

interface **ElectronReloadOptions**

```
/**
 * Enforces a hard reset for all changes (and not just the main
 * file).
 */
forceHardReset?: boolean
```

So, try with:

```
const path = require('path');

require('electron-reload')([__dirname], {
  electron: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', '.bin', 'electron'),
  forceHardReset: true
});
```

But I want to reload only the changes in a specific directory, like ./app ....

```
const path = require('path');

require('electron-reload')(
  [
    path.join(__dirname, "app"),
  ],
  {
    electron: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', '.bin', 'electron'),
    forceHardReset: true
  }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a naive implementation without using any external dependencies:

```
function decounce(func, ms) {
    let ts;
    return function() {
        clearTimeout(ts);
        ts = setTimeout(() => func.apply(this, arguments), ms);
    };
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    const fs = require('fs');

    fs.watch(
        path.resolve('./electron-build'),
        { encoding: 'buffer' },
        decounce((eventType, filename) => {
            win && win.reload();
        }, 50)
    );
}
```

`win` is an instance of `BrowserWindow`